# How to access url of Remote Video, Document and Image inside twig template?

Tags: theming, media, 9

I have a field called **Media** (machine name: field_media) inside of a content type. This field Media takes the media types of Remote video, Image, and Documents. **I am currently trying to render this media inside my twig template as a link to whatever media type it is**. For example, if it's a remote youtube video, the link would take you to the video or if it's a pdf document, the link would take you to the internal page to display that document.
Examples:

Document:
[image]
Remote video:
[image]

So inside my field twig template, grab the above values and for each item, place it inside an `href` attribute like so:

```
<div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}><a href={{ url_of_internal_document_image_or_remote_video }}>{{ item.content }}</a></div>
```

Inside the `href` value I've tried values such as `node.field_media.entity.field_media_oembed_video.value` (for remote video) but that didn't work.

My twig template is displaying like this:
[image]
Which looks how I want but I can't get the link to take me to the remote vid or internal pdf.

Side note:
In the Manage Display menu of my content type, I have this configuration for the field.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `node.field_media.entity.field_media_oembed_video.0`?

Comment: @shelane yea that didn't work :/ came back as null

Answer (score 3):

After quite an extensive search and with help of https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper this worked for me in a [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) Twig template, to print out the remote URL of a youtube video; managed in the Drupal core Media module.

```
{{ paragraph.field_media_1.entity.field_media_oembed_video.entity.field_media_oembed_video.value }}
```

Replace `field_media_1`  with the system name of your defined field.

Comment: awesome thanks! Crazy how long some of those variables are lol

Answer (score 1):

The name of our field is `field_images` and we have this to display a thumbnail of our video. That if statement may be the key.

```
{% if content.field_images[0]["#media"].field_media_video_embed_field.0.value %}
  {{ drupal_image(content.field_images[0]["#media"].thumbnail.entity.uri.value, 'ourimagestyle') }}
{% else %}
  {{ content.field_images[0] }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am just looking to display a link to the video not the thumbnail but that is good to know for future use

Comment: Something in this though `content.field_images[0]["#media"].field_media_video_embed_field.0.value`. If I could ever get the xdebug to work with twig, it would be easy to try to dissect what that variable breakdown looks like.

Comment: yea seems you have to flush cache everytime you want xdebug to run and even then doesn't always seem to work. I'm trying the https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper module but not much help either. Thank you though I'll look into something like that!